# Why isn't the matching of this hash happening?

Tags: php, sql, hash, passwords

I am Using **PHP version 5.4** and I have looked around for a while now for a hashing mecanism but I can't get it to work. The tricky part is validating the hashed password with another one the user tries, what am I doing wrong here?

```
  //and yes I am using password as name in this example

 $password_entered ="cucumberball";
    $password_hash = crypt($password_entered);

mysql_set_charset('utf8');
pdoConnect();

//insert hashed pass (same name and pass(hashed) for user)
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("insert into user (name,password) values (:name,:password)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $password_entered);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password_hash);
    $stmt->execute();

    //retriving password from db and checking if its correct with the login password provided
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("select password from user where name = :name LIMIT 1;");
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $password_entered);
    $stmt->execute();

    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

     if(crypt($password_entered, $password_hash) == $user->password) {
        // password is correct
        echo "WORKS";
    }else{

        echo "did not work";
    }
```

Comment: Side note: you are saving in db not-encrypted password as name...

Comment: I'm saving the password entered as name. Just for the example

Comment: [This example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php#114060) works: start from it (or use it)

Comment: Also @bmcculley answer is a good point. A suggestion: check your password system with simples text before (comment all the part concerning db). When your password check works, add tha db stuff.

Comment: okey thanks, will check it out.

Comment: Please use the functions [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to handle the password hashes. Crypt used like this will produce an unsalted DES hash which is nearly no protection for your passwords. Then make sure your database field is big enough to hold the hash, make it  `varchar(255)` to be future proof.

Comment: can't use those functions with my PHP version

Comment: @Christopher - Yes you can, there is a [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) available in form of a single php file.

Answer (score 1):

When you're comparing you are salting when encrypting the password and the password from the database is only encrypted.

`if(crypt($password_entered, $password_hash) == $user->password) {`

Also, according to the documentation you should be comparing like this

> You should pass the entire results of crypt() as the salt for
>   comparing a password, to avoid problems when different hashing
>   algorithms are used. (As it says above, standard DES-based password
>   hashing uses a 2-character salt, but MD5-based hashing uses 12.)

```
if (hash_equals($hashed_password, crypt($user_input, $hashed_password))) {
   echo "Password verified!";
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix this if statement:

```
if(hash_equals(crypt($password_entered, $password_hash), $password_hash))
{
    echo "WORKS";
}
```

Or as there is no `hash_equals` in PHP 5.4:

```
if(crypt($password_entered, $password_hash) == $password_hash)
{
    echo "WORKS";
}
```

But without `hash_equals`, your hashes are vulnerable to [timing attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack).

Also you may want to read [this manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php).

Comment: @Christopher why needs to be elaborated about "read [this manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)"?"

Comment: didn't see that link

Comment: @fusion3k Do you think `==` does the job instead of hash_equals?

Comment: @Saibot Yes, it is